What is the difference between '@{utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd')}' and '@{formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')}' in Power Automate?
I think everything is in the title, but I'll add more if it turns out to be needed.

According to Power Automate Reference Guide, the return values for both statements should be the same.
formatDateTime('<timestamp>', '<format>'?, '<locale>'?)


utcNow('<format>')


Where "format" described as:


Excellent, thank you. I wouldn't have known where to look for this.
